# ext2 driver for OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, ext2

I need to read files off an ext2 formatted HD. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried ext2fsx but it doesn't install on Snow Leopard :/

Comment: The virtualbox (or Parallels or VMWare if you have those) and fuse solutions both do work, on 10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spin up a linux VM in VirtualBox (or other) and mount it in the VM. Then you can share it to OS X using "shared feature" of the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [FUSE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/) that is purported to work.